# Binding to dynamic objects in Silverlight 4

Tags: .net, silverlight, data-binding, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I've [noticed that in .Net 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx), WPF FrameworkElements are able to bind to  IDynamicMetaObjectProvider binding sources. Will this also be the case for Silverlight 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not supported in Silverlight 4.

Comment: Pity, I was hoping to get away from using a dictionary as a binding source, which is what I do today. It's messy since it involves converters with parameters. I was hoping dynamic objects would come to my rescue.

Comment: Should I hope for it to be in SL5?